# How to nest parameters in Postman

Tags: arrays, nested, postman

I am trying to configure an API call with an array in Postman, but I'm unable to figure out how to properly configure my parameters so that the Items and Properties appears as they do in the sample below. I can't quite figure out how to next Items > Item > Properties > Property

[Here's a screenshot of what I need to send should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K1un.png)

I feel like I might be getting close, but it's still wrong.

[Here's a screenshot of my last attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoRmm.png)

Comment: Can you append SOAP XML message by text format?
``` code ``` will be share in your question, It will help to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by Postman Variable and hierarchy JSON access method.

### Steps Overview

[image]

I will shows simple demo and apply your case.

### Simple Demo

Demo - I will show [`ADD` operation](http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?op=Add) in [`Calculator`](http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx) SOAP

SOAP service URL

```
http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx
```

Using variables `input_a`, `input_b` for adding

> **1.** Assign Variable

JSON input

```
var jsonData = {
    "key_a" : {
        "data" : "2"
    },
    "key_b": {
        "data" : "3"
    }
}
```

input_a = jsonData["key_a"]["data"] = 2

input_b = jsonData["key_b"]["data"] = 3

- In `Pre-request Script` section in Postman

[image]

> **2.** Apply XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <intA>{{input_a}}</intA>
      <intB>{{input_b}}</intB>
    </Add>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

- In `input Body` section in Postman

[image]

> **3.** SOAP/POST Call

- In `outputBody` section in Postman

[image]

> **4.** XML Parsing

- In `Tests` section in Postman

```
var xmlTree = xml2Json(responseBody);
var text = xmlTree["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"]["AddResponse"]["AddResult"];
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("output_result", Number(text));
console.log(postman.getEnvironmentVariable("output_result"));
```

[image]

> **5.** Result

`output_result` =  `input_a`  + `input_b`

`5` = `2` + `3`

[image]

### Complicate Demo - your question

Apply in your case by same idea(Simple Demo)

> **1.** Assign Variable at Pre-request Script

```js
var jsonData = {
    "username" : "tom",
    "password" : "1234",
    "subscriptionId" : "sub-125abdv1",
    "items": [
        {
            "item" : {
                "id" : "CN #00168927",
                "properties" : [
                    {
                        "property" : {
                            "name" : "ssn",
                            "value" : "555-01-0001",
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "property" : {
                            "name" : "lastName",
                            "value" : "James",
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "item" : {
                "id" : "CN #00927119",
                "properties" : [
                    {
                        "property" : {
                            "name" : "firstName",
                            "value" : "Jack",
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "property" : {
                            "name" : "lastName",
                            "value" : "Doyle",
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "property" : {
                            "name" : "ssn",
                            "value" : "555-01-0002",
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
console.log("username = " + jsonData["username"]);
console.log("password = " + jsonData["password"]);
console.log("subscriptionId = " + jsonData["subscriptionId"]);

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("username", jsonData["username"]);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("password", jsonData["password"]);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("subscriptionId", jsonData["subscriptionId"]);

console.log("items[0] id = " + jsonData["items"][0]["item"]["id"]);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("item_zero_id", jsonData["items"][0]["item"]["id"]);

console.log("items[0] properties[0] name = " + jsonData["items"][0]["item"]["properties"][0]["property"]["name"]);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("item_zero_property_zero_name", jsonData["items"][0]["item"]["properties"][0]["property"]["name"]);

console.log("items[0] properties[0] value = " + jsonData["items"][0]["item"]["properties"][0]["property"]["value"]);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("item_zero_property_zero_value", jsonData["items"][0]["item"]["properties"][0]["property"]["value"]);

console.log("items[0] properties[1] name = " + jsonData["items"][0]["item"]["properties"][1]["property"]["name"]);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("item_zero_property_one_name", jsonData["items"][0]["item"]["properties"][1]["property"]["name"]);

console.log("items[0] properties[1] value = " + jsonData["items"][0]["item"]["properties"][1]["property"]["value"]);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("item_zero_property_one_value", jsonData["items"][0]["item"]["properties"][1]["property"]["value"]);

console.log("items[1] id = " + jsonData["items"][1]["item"]["id"]);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("item_one_id", jsonData["items"][1]["item"]["id"]);


console.log("items[1] properties[0] name = " + jsonData["items"][1]["item"]["properties"][0]["property"]["name"]);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("item_one_property_zero_name", jsonData["items"][1]["item"]["properties"][0]["property"]["name"]);

console.log("items[1] properties[0] value = " + jsonData["items"][1]["item"]["properties"][0]["property"]["value"]);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("item_one_property_zero_value", jsonData["items"][1]["item"]["properties"][0]["property"]["value"]);

console.log("items[1] properties[1] name = " + jsonData["items"][1]["item"]["properties"][1]["property"]["name"]);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("item_one_property_one_name", jsonData["items"][1]["item"]["properties"][1]["property"]["name"]);

console.log("items[1] properties[1] value = " + jsonData["items"][1]["item"]["properties"][1]["property"]["value"]);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("item_one_property_one_value", jsonData["items"][1]["item"]["properties"][1]["property"]["value"]);

console.log("items[1] properties[2] name = " + jsonData["items"][1]["item"]["properties"][2]["property"]["name"]);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("item_one_property_two_name", jsonData["items"][1]["item"]["properties"][2]["property"]["name"]);

console.log("items[1] properties[2] value = " + jsonData["items"][1]["item"]["properties"][2]["property"]["value"]);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("item_one_property_two_value", jsonData["items"][1]["item"]["properties"][2]["property"]["value"]);
```

[image]

> **2.** Apply XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AddPortfolioItemsRequest xmlns="http://www.bkwservice.com/api/2022-08-01">
    <username>{{username}}</username>
    <password>{{password}}</password>
    <subscriptionId>{{subscriptionId}}</subscriptionId>
    <items>
        <item>
            <id>{{item_zero_id}}</id>
            <properties>
                <property>
                    <name>{{item_zero_property_zero_name}}</name>
                    <value>{{item_zero_property_zero_value}}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>{{item_zero_property_one_name}}</name>
                    <value>{{item_zero_property_one_value}}</value>
                </property>
            </properties>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>{{item_one_id}}</id>
            <properties>
                <property>
                    <name>{{item_one_property_zero_name}}</name>
                    <value>{{item_one_property_zero_value}}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>{{item_one_property_one_name}}</name>
                    <value>{{item_one_property_one_value}}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>{{item_one_property_two_name}}</name>
                    <value>{{item_one_property_two_value}}</value>
                </property>
            </properties>
        </item>
    </items>
</AddPortfolioItemsRequest>
```

[image]